# Prove that $d(x,y) :\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is a distance function.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

$$
d(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\|x-y\| & \text{if }x\text{ and }y\text{ are linearly dependent} \\
\|x\|+\|y\| &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I am stuck. Do I use the definition of a metric space?

Comment: "Do I use the definition of a metric space?" That's a good idea.

Comment: Remember that distance function is a metric.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, show that your function $d$ satisfies the properties of a metric.

By the way, it might help your intuition to visualize $\Bbb{R}^2$ as a star (or hedgehog) of radial rays pointing out from the origin.  The distance from one point to another is always measured along these rays.  If the two points lie on the same ray, then you measure along the usual interval, else you have to visit the origin before heading out to the other point.

This is sometimes called the [*Paris metric*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_space#Paris_metric) since the major streets in Paris (to a rough approximation) are laid out like radial spokes.

Comment: Curiously, in France this metric is rather known as *distance SNCF*, in reference to the French rail network organized around Paris.